# E Classifieds domain model to buy

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm learning `nhibernate` and I want to put my skills on the practical application where I will using code first approach, serialization of nhib. session factory configuration object, asp.net mvc caching and nhibernate session per web request, ...

Since I do not want to investigate core domain model (not have enough time to recognize bussiness process) I want to buy domain model diagram with associations between entities.

Domain model in which I'm interested is `Online Classifieds`.

I already googled but I cannot find any, free or paid one.

Is there such a site with uml diagrams based on industry where interested party can download domain model or find some futher information.

Thanks

Comment: Never heard of such a thing. I'm suspecting that it does not exist for the reasons eulerfx outlined: there is no way, that a model designed for one business process will seamlessly work with another.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you obtain a reference model, you still have to implement it in your project which would effectively require full familiarization with the model. Moreover, your project will likely require deviations from the model. Overall, you can't expect to drop some sort of model artifact into your project and expect things to work seamlessly.

For inspiration however, it is good to look how other domains are modeled. [Effective Aggregate Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=139) is a great resource for this. It models a domain and then addresses all the technical concerns, with considerations including persistence with an ORM.

I've found reference model collections to be somewhat helpful, but without an approach to implementation, they can be somewhat misleading.